# get the observations for chi2 test

Tags: matlab

We have a collection of Data that we can draw a histogram with the specified distribution curve on and get the centers of bins, using:

```
[counts,centers]=hist(Data,14)
h=histfit(Data,14,'normal')
```

we can get the 100 point XData and YData of the drawn curve, using:

```
h(2).XData
h(2).YData
```

How can we find the YData of the curve corresponding to the bin centers of the histogram of Data (in commands without knowing the curve equation)?
Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Fit a normal distribution to `Data` using [`fitdist`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitdist.html) and compute the values using the parameters of that distribution. If you don't want to do that, you can get an approximation by interpolating with the `XData` and `YData` from the curve drawn with [`interp1`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html).

Comment: @ mikkola Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use fitdistr

```
 %Generate data
r=randn(100,1); 
[counts,centers]=hist(r,20)   %r=Data in your case

%fit a Gaussian
pd=fitdist(r(:),'normal')

pd = 
  NormalDistribution

  Normal distribution
       mu = 0.0700439   [-0.111376, 0.251463]
    sigma =  0.914313   [0.802773, 1.06213]


x=-3:0.1:3;  
PDF=pdf(pd,x); %PDF is a vector of y values: it's our fit

%overplot
PDF=PDF/max(PDF); 
%scale to y axis
y=ylim;
PDF=PDF*y(2);

hold on
plot(x,PDF,'r-','LineWidth',2)
hold off
```

Comment: i want to get the y values on the curve corresponding to given x vales to perform the chi-square test

Comment: you can make a chi2 test between 'counts' and 'PDF' I think.. just choose the right length/points of 'PDF'. I'm not sure to get the question though..is that it?

Comment: I don't understand the chi2 test (built-in function's) results and I want to use the regular steps to get the chi2 value (sum((Observed-Expected)^2/(Expected))) that's why i need the curve values

Comment: then if your expected function is a gaussian just use 'centers' as variable.

Comment: @ A_C histogram's centers are the x values I need the corresponding y values on the curve

Comment: @user3332603 those are the 'PDF' values.